# Hidden markov models implementation in .net?

Tags: .net, hidden-markov-models

Does anyone know of any HMM implementation in .net?

I've some stuff that I did that was basicly reverse engineered from what little knowledge that I have regarding the subject and some c++ code of a very domain specific application that one of my professors did.

I want to improve it somewhat and having another's work that is in the same language to compare to can really help to see if I've got it right or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick Google search returned this [C# implementation](http://corsis.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/corsis/trunk/Tenka.Text/Tenka.Text/Statistics/MarkovNGramm.cs?view=markup) of what appears to be a Hidden Markov Model (they said it was an [n-gram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram), but the implementation appears to be an HMM).

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure it's very late, but maybe this will serve for reference for other people looking: the [Accord.NET](http://accord-net.origo.ethz.ch/) framework integrates a simple, efficient implementation of HMMs.